# Направление и анимация потоков

Tags: windows, анимация, технологии

[Есть несколько вариантов направления воды через ёмкости](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCZ22.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCZ22.jpg) Подскажите пожалуйста как и где можно воссоздать это в электронном варианте? Пример: поток воды идёт через аппараты 1-4-8, потом произошли изменения я вошёл в программу и изменил анимацию течения в пару кликов через аппараты 1-4-9. Существуют ли готовые программы для таких задач, если нет то на каком языке программирования это лучше сделать? Заранее большое спасибо за ваш  ответ.

Comment: Ты мультик рисуешь или канализацию проектируешь?

Comment: Нужно сделать схему приятную глазу, анимированную и изменяемую прям на сайте.

Comment: Ну из бесплатных - `Blender`.